# How to delete data from Cassandra table with TWCS and counter column?

Tags: cassandra

I have a table that uses TWCS including a counter column:

```
create table sensors_by_time (
            group text,     // sensor group
            date date,       // bucketing
            id text,        // sensor id 
            count counter,  // detected count
        primary key ((group, date), id))
        WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (id DESC)
        AND compaction = {
            'compaction_window_size': '24',
            'compaction_window_unit': 'HOURS',
            'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.TimeWindowCompactionStrategy'}
```

After a week I have 7 sstables (1 for each day). I need the data for 7 days so i thought to use ttl and gc_grace_seconds but Cassandra doe's not support ttl on table with counter column..

My other option is use some job to delete data older than 7 days but I understand that It's not good for my performance because of the TWCS: http://www.redshots.com/cassandra-twcs-must-have-ttls/

How should i delete old data from such a table?

Comment: Have tried with gc_grace_seconds=0 without adding TTL in the table?

Comment: And use a delete query for deletion? isn't it a problem because the delete is on data that already compacted (because it belongs to a previous time window)?

Comment: So you are saying with gc_grace_seconds=0 and after compaction still data will be there?

Comment: lets say my window is one day, and i want to delete it after 7 days. now i have some data and after 24 hours compaction will write the last 24 hours data to an immutable sstable. after a week i will run a delete command on all the data older than a week. tombstone will be created in another window so i'm not sure how the gc grace seconds will help?

Comment: If your window is 24 hrs then after compaction I don't think so any data will remain after.

Comment: not sure what do you mean, after the 24 hours window compaction will compact all the window sstables to one sstable of the window

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm resurrecting an old question, but I ran into a similar problem, and wrote a tool to help solve it. On each node, you'll have to:

- stop the cassandra process
- delete the SSTables that contain the old records
- start the process again

The difficult part is knowing which SSTables contain date ranges you're no longer interested in. Cassandra comes with a tool, `sstablemetadata`, that display SSTable metadata, including the Min/Max timestamps.

`sstablemetadata` is slow, and the output is difficult to process. Instead try `ls-sstm`, which outputs nicely formatted tabular data about each SSTable within a Cassandra table directory: https://github.com/lokkju/cassandra-tools/blob/main/ls-sstm.sh